# How to change the content of grid items without using 'vw' units?

Tags: html, css, grid, flex3

I'm quite new to building grid layouts. I'm trying to change the dimensions of the content in the grid elements via pixels, percentages, but they remain the same, only viewport units work. There are grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows allow to increase the size of the content. I'm trying to make the top two elements: logo and menu hamburger, get bigger and almost adjacent to each other. And, I noticed that if reduce the height of the visible area of the screen, then the elements increase. Why can't I "simply" increase these two elements without doing this is beyond me? Below is a piece of code and one screenshot of what the mobile version looks like now, and how it should. Please check what is wrong.

```css
    * {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
            font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
            height: 100vh;
}
        .container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 10%);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 5%);
            height: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .logo {
            grid-column: 1 / 10;
            grid-row: 1 / 4;
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding-left: 3%;
        }
        .logo img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .header {
            grid-column: 10 / 11;
            grid-row: 1 / 4;
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .gsi {
            background-color: #1b8183;
            grid-column: 1 / 6;
            grid-row: 8 / 17;
            z-index: 1;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            align-items: start;
            padding-left: 7%;
        }
        /* Text */
        .gsi h1 {
        font-family: 'TT Norms', Helvetica Now, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 3vw;
        color: #ffffff;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
        .gsi h1::after {
         display: inline-block;
         vertical-align: middle;
         content: "";
         height: 1px;
         position: relative;
         background-color: #ffffff;
         width: 4vw;
         right: -0.5em;
}
        .gsi p {
         font-family: 'TT Norms', Helvetica Now, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
         font-size: 2vw;
         color: #ffffff;
         margin: 0;
         white-space: nowrap;
}
        .button {
        font-family: 'TT Norms', Helvetica Now, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5vw;
        background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0);
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 3em / 3em;
        color: white;
        padding: 1% 7.5%;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
}
        .pillar {
         grid-column: 5 / 11;
         grid-row: 4 / 21;
}
        .pillar img {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         object-fit: cover;
}
/* Anything related to hamburger */
        .logo-text a:active,
        .logo-text a:hover,
        .logo-text a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #1b8183;
        font-size: 2vw;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        .menu-btn {
            height: 70px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 3;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-right: 50px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .menu-btn span {
            width: 50px;
            height: 4px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background-color: #538b99;
            border: 1px solid #538b99;
            border-radius: 10px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .menu-btn span:nth-of-type(2) {
            top: calc(40% - 5px);
        }
        .menu-btn span:nth-of-type(3) {
            top: calc(60% + 5px);
        }
        .menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
            display: none;
        }
        .menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
        }
        .menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(3) {
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(-45deg);
        }
        .menu {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            background: #f8f8f8;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s;
        }

        .menu.active {
            transform: translateX(0);
            z-index: 2; /* > gsi =1  & < menu.active = 3 */
        }
        .menu li {
            list-style-type: none;
            font-family: 'TT Norms', Helvetica Now, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 2vw;
            padding-top: 2%;
        }
        .menu.active nav {
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .menu.active nav a {
            position: relative;
            color: black;
            cursor: pointer;
            line-height: 1;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .menu.active nav a:after {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0; 
            width: 0; 
            height: 3.5px;
            background-color: black;
            content: "";
            transition: width 0.4s ease-out;
}
        .menu.active nav a:hover:after,
        .menu.active nav a:focus:after {
            width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
        <title>Web-site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/bYD24JGb/logo.png" alt="логотип"></a></div>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="menu-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="gsi"><h1>NAME</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><input type="button" class="button" value="Compose"></div>
        <div class="pillar"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hxMnrVX/pillar.png" alt="Pillar"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: The first two images of the collage from left to right are what is now, I underlined in one color, and then what I would like to get in the end]

Comment: Could you check the CSS in your question as it has errors.

Comment: I looked in 4 places, including local machine. Only two errors that are related to connecting fonts. What is displayed on this site is clearly not an error in the code. The best thing is devtools.

Comment: I put the CSS that you have given in your question and there are errors. Please correct them.

Comment: Where did you put them? And what are the errors? Ive just re-copied the code from here and ran it on my laptop.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND TTNorms-Regular.ttf:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND TTNorms-Regular.woff:1
I don't see any more errors.
https://codepen.io/paulmclaren/pen/MWBbPwJ - there are also show only two errors. Well, it's not the fonts that are the problem:)

Comment: Hi, I’m not talking about when it’s run, I’m looking at the CSS you have provided and it’s actually fairly obviously something missing after the body setting. I ran it through the W3c validator. If we don’t have complete code it’s difficult to help.

Comment: Hi, I fixed it, it was really missing. I even forgot that there is such a thing as a W3C validator:)